# Xamarin Forms Unit Testing a Command

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, mocking, moq

I am trying to unit test a Command in Xamarin.Forms.

I have my view-model class as an example like this

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    public Command SelectedCommand { get; } => new Command(OnSelected);

    public Car SelectedCar
    {
      get { return _selectedCar; }
      private set { _selectedCar = value; }
    }

    private void OnSelected(object obj)
    {
      if (obj is Car car) 
      {
        SelectedCar = car;
      }
    }
}
```

This class is the `BindingContext` for my view and the `SelectedCommand` above is fired when user taps on a ListView item, so it is a method that is bound to a `Command` in XAML using a `TapGestureRecognizer` like

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" .../>
```

I am trying to unit test this class, so my `CarViewModel` class is subject under test (SUT) inside my test.

I just started looking at mocking libraries / isolation frameworks and I see Moq is quite popular.

My questions are:

1. Since I dont have any dependencies in my `CarViewModel` below, I dont think I need to mock that class in my test.  It is subject under test which to my understanding should not be mocked.  Only dependencies should be mocked.  Is this correct?
2. How do I unit test to confirm that my `SelectedCommand` has been called and that it has set `SelectedCar` property?  If I am right in 1 above, then Moq is not even needed to test this since I have no dependency to mock for my `CarViewModel` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the current code in the example provided there really is no need to mock anything.

Execute the command on the SUT with a known parameter and verify the expected behavior via the `SelectedCar`.

```
[Test]
public void SelectedCommand_Should_Set_SelectedCar {
    // Arrange
    var expected = new Car();
    var subject = new CarViewModel();

    // Act
    subject.SelectedCommand.Execute(expected);

    // Assert    
    var actual = subject.SelectedCar;    
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```